# How to process a vector as an asynchronous stream?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

In my [RSS reader project](https://github.com/Riduidel/rrss2imap), I want to read my RSS feeds asynchronously. Currently, they're read synchronously thanks to [this code block](https://github.com/Riduidel/rrss2imap/blob/master/src/store.rs#L135-L138)

```
self.feeds = self
    .feeds
    .iter()
    .map(|f| f.read(&self.settings))
    .collect::<Vec<Feed>>();
```

I want to make that code asynchronous, because it will allow me to better handle poor web server responses.

I understand I can use a `Stream` that I can create from my `Vec` using `stream::from_iter(...)` which transforms the code into something like

```
self.feeds = stream::from_iter(self.feeds.iter())
    .map(|f| f.read(&self.settings))
    // ???
    .collect::<Vec<Feed>>()
}
```

But then, I have two questions

1. How to have results joined into a `Vec` (which is a synchronous struct)?
2. How to execute that stream? I was thinking about using `task::spawn` but it doesn't seems to work ...

Comment: so you ask how to do async in rust ? That big, I will be happy to read an answer on that but I think it's too broad. Anyway, you need something that will run the task, I think the (only ?) one is a city named [tokio](https://tokio.rs/). There is a lot of resource but I'm didn't look recently so I don't know if there have update tutorial to use async feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to execute that stream? I was thinking about using `task::spawn` but it doesn't seems to work

In the `async/await` world, asynchronous code is meant to be executed by an executor, which is not part of the standard library but provided by third-party crates such as [`tokio`](https://tokio.rs/). `task::spawn` only schedules one instance of `async fn` to run, not actually running it.

> How to have results joined into a vec (which is a sync struct)

The bread and butter of your rss reader seems to be `f.read`. It should be turned into an asynchronous function. Then the vector of feeds will be mapped into a vector of futures, which need to be polled to completion.

The `futures` crate has `futures::stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered` to help you do that. `FuturesUnordered` itself implements `Stream` trait. This stream is then collected into the result vector and `await`ed to completion like so:

```rust
//# tokio = { version = "0.2.4", features = ["full"] }
//# futures = "0.3.1"
use tokio::time::delay_for;
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use futures::stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered;
use std::error::Error;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let feeds = (0..10).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let res = read_feeds(feeds).await;
    dbg!(res);
    dbg!(start.elapsed());

    Ok(())
}

async fn read_feeds(feeds: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
    feeds.iter()
        .map(read_feed)
        .collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .await
}

async fn read_feed(feed: &u32) -> u32 {
    delay_for(Duration::from_millis(500)).await;

    feed * 2
}
```

`delay_for` is to simulate the potentially expensive operation. It also helps to demonstrate that these readings indeed happen concurrently without any explicit thread related logic.

One nuance here. Unlike its synchronous counterpart, the results of reading rss feeds aren't in the same order of feeds themselves any more, whichever returns the first will be at the front. You need to deal with that somehow.

Comment: Just as an aside, I don't care about order in which feeds appear after having read them, so it's not really a problem.

Comment: In fact, the most annoying part is that I get `the return type of a function must have a statically known size` because I try to return a `Vec<Feed>` which indeed is of unkown size. So how can I avoid that problem ?

Comment: Well, ok, i've understood. Now it will be good to have these futures run parallel